# PhD or physics as a hobby?

Tags: phd, early-career

I completed my undergraduate degree in physics in a good university (outside the US). Because of financial commitments, I couldn't leave for grad school straight away. So I worked for a couple of years as a research assistant at the same university after I graduated. I did very well, got three papers out in around three years and picked up a master's by research for that. I loved my time working in physics but the research assistant job was a temp job at best and I eventually had to leave it.

Now I work at a well known engineering company. The job is relaxed and spare time is plenty and I'm being paid well. There are good opportunities for growth because the company is about to expand in a big way. I also love having enough time for hobbies, fitness and just life in general.

I also applied to PhD programs in the US and was accepted into several good ones. The reason I applied is primarily because I miss physics and I am interested in being really good at core physics. I have this feeling that my education is unfinished in some way. I want to be that guy who has a deep understanding of fundamental physics. That guy who can easily answer questions on the physics stacks. Maybe I'd even like to write a textbook someday. I liked research when I did it but to be honest, I'm not sure I have that same fierce passion for it as I do for learning. In addition to this, I know I'm not cut out for the academic tenure track - Even if I were smart enough (and this is not impostor syndrome or anything, I am self aware enough know that I am good but not great), I have no interest in chasing low paid postdocs and living with the general instability of post PhD life. In five years, when I complete my PhD, I will likely end up in a very similar job to what I have now.

With this in mind, should I simply stay in my regular job and do physics as a side hobby or actually do the PhD?

TL;DR Is it worth doing a PhD if learning and mastery of physics over research is the primary motivation and sacrifice a great career for it?

Comment: This really depends on your personal preferences. We can only help with information, not with decisions. Is there anything you need to know?

Comment: Asides from @henning's correct statement, it is possible to do both - as a study and as a hobby, something to consider.

Comment: _when I complete my PhD, I will likely end up in a very similar job to what I have now_ Based on my over 30 years of industry experience, I am not sure about that. I mean you may not be able to find another industry job that can give you enough time for hobbies, fitness and just life in general.

Comment: Primarily goal of PhD is to learn independent research. That is something you don't care at all, so why would you do it?

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is to do both, in a way.

To help explain, I am drawing on my own *current* experience -  I earned my PhD in Physics back in 2014, but I still work in a different field. However, I continue research in Physics (and am still getting published) as an Adjunct researcher to the university where I completed the PhD. (Of course, you should check with the university if it is possible to be an Adjunct).

Completing a PhD can provide a foundation for you to continue research in an area of interest as an Adjunct (especially if you published while completing the PhD). Analytical and research skills developed in the PhD could potentially greatly benefit your work in your job (as I have found in my situation).

As in your case, my job allows a considerable amount of spare time, where I have found plenty of time to continue to do research, exercise and engage in my hobbies in my time.

Depending on your time constraints, there is no reason to give up either.

Comment: Do you think your PhD is necessary to do the work you do?

Comment: My paid work - not necessarily, but it has helped. In terms of the Adjunct research, it has provided a foundation for the research that I still publish in.

Answer (score 4):

I realize a lot of people who participate in Academia SE feel that PhDs are all about doing original research.  However, a PhD is also a path to teaching at the college level.  Furthermore, full-time physics grad studies might lead you to conclude that at a certain point, you feel satisfied, at which point, you could withdraw from the program (perhaps with a master's).  Or, you might get interested in a research project and keep going.

Why not start by putting a foot in the water -- taking one physics course at a time while you continue in your current job?  Perhaps your company will even pay your tuition.

Taking some courses in this way might make your decision easier.